# Raspbian - Network-Manager 0.9.6 or newer?

Tags: raspbian, networking

I am using the RPi CLI only.  I would like to use Network-Manager as I do on my ubuntu system (v0.9.8).  I have installed NM on my dev RPi (via apt-get), but looks like 0.9.4 is latest available.  Is there any repository that has 0.9.6 or later that i can install?  I would rather not have to grab the source and compile.
(I want the "nmcli dev wifi connect" capability that 0.9.6 introduced.)

Thanks for any advice.